ActiveMQ Artemis and stomp.py using client acknowledgment not behaving as expected
I can't get the ack='client' to behave as expected. I think that a message consumed by the code below should nack it and send it to the DLQ. But no! The message just disappears. I guess that it is considered processed.If, on the other hand, I just throw an error, it does end up in the DLQ.
I want to ack it if all is well, and nack it if it does not work as expected.
Producer.py:
import stomp

# STOMP server configuration
server = 'localhost'
port = 61613
username = 'artemis'
password = 'artemis'
destination = 'your.queue.name'
message = 'hello :-)'

# Create a connection to the STOMP server
conn = stomp.Connection([(server, port)])
conn.set_listener('', stomp.PrintingListener())

# Connect to the server
conn.connect(username, password, wait=True)

# Send a durable message to the specified destination
conn.send(destination=destination, body=message, headers={'persistent': 'true'})

# Disconnect from the server
conn.disconnect()

Consumer.py:
import stomp
import time

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def on_error(self, frame):
        print('Received an error:')
        print(f'Headers: {frame.headers}')
        print(f'Body: {frame.body}')

    def on_message(self, frame):
        print('Received a message:')
        print(f'Headers: {frame.headers}')
        print(f'Body: {frame.body}')
        
        time.sleep(1)
        
        #self.conn.ack(frame.headers['message-id'], frame.headers['subscription'])
        
        # This line ha no effect 4 what I can tell.
        self.conn.nack(frame.headers['message-id'], frame.headers['subscription'])
        
        #error will send it DLQ!
        #raise Exception("I will send this message to DLQ!")
        print('Done!!!')

def main():
    server = 'localhost'
    port = 61613
    username = 'artemis'
    password = 'artemis'
    destination = 'your.queue.name'

    conn = stomp.Connection([(server, port)], heartbeats=(4000, 4000))
    conn.set_listener('', MyListener(conn))

    try:
        conn.connect(username, password, wait=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to connect to STOMP server: {e}')
        return

    try:
        # Ack modes:
        # stuff I tried:
        # client-individual
        # https://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html
        # client
        # https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.4.0/pre-acknowledge.html
        # CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE

        conn.subscribe(destination=destination, id='1', ack='client', headers={'subscription-type': 'ANYCAST'})
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to subscribe to queue: {e}')
        conn.disconnect()
        return

    print('Waiting for messages...')
    
    # Keep the main thread alive to receive messages
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Disconnecting...')
        conn.disconnect()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An unexpected error occurred: {e}')
        conn.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

broker.xml:
...
<addresses>
...
    <address name="your.queue.name">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="your.queue.name" />
        </anycast>
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ.your.queue.name</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>5000</redelivery-delay> <!-- 5 seconds delay before redelivery -->
        <max-delivery-attempts>1</max-delivery-attempts> <!-- Max attempts before moving to DLQ -->
        <redelivery-delay-multiplier>2.0</redelivery-delay-multiplier> <!-- Exponential backoff -->
        <max-redelivery-delay>60000</max-redelivery-delay> <!-- Max delay of 1 minute -->
    </address>
    
    <address name="DLQ.your.queue.name">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="DLQ.your.queue.name" />
        </anycast>
    </address>
...
</addresses>
...


What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Can you confirm that the XML you pasted from your broker.xml is valid? According to the XSD that XML is not valid.

Artemis: 2.31.0
Hawtio: 2.17.6
Hawtio Core: 4.16.5
Hawtio Integration: 5.4.0
Hawtio OAuth: 4.13.15

The XML is parsed, and the queue is created along with the DLQ. So it's OK. :-)

When I copy & paste the your.queue.name address into the broker.xml of a fresh instance of 2.31.0 the broker won't start and logs, "AMQ214019: Invalid configuration...Invalid content was found starting with element '{"urn:activemq:core":dead-letter-address}'. One of '{"urn:activemq:core":multicast}' is expected." Most of the settings you have for this address belong in the address-settings block since that's what they are. See the documentation.

The behavior you're seeing is, in fact, the expected behavior. As noted in the STOMP 1.2 specification regarding the NACK frame (emphasis mine):

NACK is the opposite of ACK. It is used to tell the server that the client did not consume the message. The server can then either send the message to a different client, discard it, or put it in a dead letter queue. The exact behavior is server specific.

ActiveMQ Artemis discards messages which are nacked. This behavior is not configurable.
If you want more control over the semantics here I recommend using a STOMP transaction.

Ok.
The use case is that I need to know if the processing of the message was successful or not. It's an important message.
If there is no difference between ACK and NACK from a use-case perspective STOMP can only be used for trivial use cases in combination with Artemis and not in any situation that requires client-specific acknowledgment?

Have you tried using a STOMP transaction for your use-case? I expect that would give you the control you want.

According to the documentation, transactions are not implemented:
https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#limitations
