ActiveMQ Artemis (with Python/Stomp-py) - Nack not resulting in DLQ
I'm trying to setup a queue with a DLQ. From everything I understand from online and all the examples I've read it should be enough to cap the max-delivery-attempts in order for a messages to be send to it's DLQ. The queue and address are configured as Anycast, other settings left as default.
<max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>

I am running Artemis in Docker and have completely started fresh (version 2.34.0). All I did was add the max-delivery-attempts to the generic address settings <address-setting match="#">. I also tried to config a specific address <address-setting match="dev_queue">
My message is send as follows:
conn.send(body=f'message:  {datetime.now()}', destination='dev_queue')

And my test-receive script is as follows:
import time
import stomp


class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):

    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def on_message(self, frame):
        self.conn.nack(frame.headers['message-id'], frame.headers['subscription'])
        print(f'nacked {frame.body}')


conn = stomp.Connection()
while True:
    if not conn.is_connected():
        conn = stomp.Connection(
            host_and_ports=[('192.168.1.51', 61614)],
            heartbeats=(5000, 5000),
            reconnect_attempts_max=1)
        conn.set_listener('', Listener(conn))
        conn.connect('artemis', 'artemis', wait=True)
        conn.subscribe(destination='dev_queue', id=1, ack='client')
    time.sleep(1)

conn.disconnect()


In the end I expect the nack to result in the message being send to the DLQ, but somehow all my message show up as acknowledged in Artemis and nothing is ever send to it's DLQ. What am I missing here?

This question seems very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78556673/activemq-artemis-and-stomp-py-using-client-acknowledgment-not-behaving-as-expect/78556802#78556802, see the answer of Justin Bertram https://stackoverflow.com/a/78556802/6982270

Thanks @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino! I have no idea why this question never showed up in any of my search results, but it clarifies my problem indeed
